# Is there a good way to choose the right platform on the fly?

Tags: opencl

Because this is the computer I am using it has AMD, NVIDEA, and Intel platforms. How can I know which is the right platform to use on a users computer? What I have now is a loop that tries to create a platform, device, context, and queue for every platform. If it fails at any point it tries the next platform.

```
    readKernel();

    numPlatforms = getNumPlatforms(); TEST
    platforms = getPlatforms(); TEST
    for(int i = 0; i < numPlatforms; i++)
    {
        numDevices = getNumDevices(platforms[i]); TEST_AND_CONTINUE
        devices = getDevices(platforms[i], numDevices); TEST_AND_CONTINUE
        context = createContext(platforms[i], devices); TEST_AND_CONTINUE
        queue = getCommandQueue(context, devices[0]); TEST_AND_CONTINUE

        // all setup. can post info here ->  getDeviceInfo(devices[0]);
        break; 
    }
    program = createProgram(context, source); TEST
    buildProgram(program); TEST
    kernel = buildKernel(program, appName); TEST
```

Is that a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual with this kind of question, the answer is: It depends on your need. Or in other words, you need to define what is "the right platform".

Here are some cases I can think of (I'm sure anybody can find some others):

- You developed your kernel using some features specific to a certain version of OCL.  Using `clGetPlatformInfo`, you query each platform present to find one that has the proper OCL version.
- You optimized your kernel for a specific type of device (CPU, GPU). You filter the devices you are interested in using the appropriate flag (`CL_DEVICE_TYPE_TYPENAME`) with `clGetDeviceIDs`.
- You want to parallelized as much as possible the computation, but you have to move a lot of data to the device. In that case you might have found out that running your kernel on an iGPU gives the best performance. Thanks to the function `clGetDeviceInfo` and the flag `CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY` you can determine if you have such a device available.
- With the `clGetDeviceInfo` function you can also query for a specific vendor extension that you want to use (flag: `CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS`). Note that `clGetPlatformInfo` provides also a list of extension supported by the platform.
- You have several GPUs available and you want the one with the "best performance". Still with `clGetDeviceInfo` you can query certain specifications of the device. Based on these specs you can make you choice. For instance you can found out if the device has cache (`CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_TYPE`) and if yes how much (`CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE`). You can also query the clock frequency (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY`) or how many compute units are available on the device (`CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`).

Comment: Also consider using all suitable devices in parallel to accelerate execution on machines that have multiple GPUs. But be aware that the single CPU device can show up under more than one platform even though only one of the platform instances of it can be used.

Answer (score 4):

Typically a good common use case is to:

1. Get all the platforms
2. Get each platform GPU and CPU/Other devices, separate them into 2 arrays.
3. Is there a GPU device available? Select that platform&device
4. Is there a CPU/Other device available? Select that platform&device

You can refine the 3 and 4 points, to selec only the best GPU device depending on your needs with `clGetDeviceInfo()`.

Comment: If really motivated, add code that runs a short benchmark on each candidate device so that the one most suitable for the problem at hand can be chosen.